# adding dependencies in subproject causes failure

Tags: gradle

I have a dependencies section in my master build.gradle file

```
subprojects {
   dependencies {
   }
}
```

Then I add one to my subproject as only that one is using two local dependencies and that breaks everything with the failure below

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework', include: '*.jar')
}
```

> You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!

googling this error yields lots of results but I can't seem to decipher from them how to fix this?

NOTE: This did work if I injected the dependencies instead....why is that?

```
project(':webserver') {
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

**ONE IMPORTANT NOTE: I am not sure if it matters, by my actual master build.gradle is ONE LINE that imports the following one (as I could not get the "master" folder to work out).  could that be the problem?**

FULL master build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    buildDir = 'output'

    task hello << { task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
    build << { task -> println "MASTER: I'm building now classpath=$sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.files" }
}

subprojects {

    version = 'Developer-Build'
    project.ext.genLibDir = file('lib')
    project.ext.fixedLibDir = file('libother')

    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
    }

    //configurations.compile {
    //  exclude group: 'javax.jms',        module: 'jms'
    //  exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk',     module: 'jmxtools'
    //  exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx',      module: 'jmxri'
    //}

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'org.hibernate',   name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '4.1.4.Final'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j',       name: 'slf4j-api',               version: '1.6.6'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j',       name: 'log4j-over-slf4j',        version: '1.6.6'
        compile group: 'ch.qos.logback',  name: 'logback-core',            version: '1.0.6'
        compile group: 'joda-time',       name: 'joda-time',               version: '2.1'
        compile group: 'com.google.inject',name: 'guice',                  version: '3.0'
        compile group: 'com.google.protobuf',name: 'protobuf-java',        version: '2.4.1'


        //to be erased soon
        compile group: 'commons-configuration',name:'commons-configuration',version: '1.8'
        compile group: 'org.jboss.netty', name: 'netty',                   version: '3.2.7.Final'

        //compile group: 'org.asteriskjava',name: 'asterisk-java',         version: '1.0.0.M3'            
        compile fileTree(dir: project.ext.fixedLibDir, include: '*.jar')

    }

    task('copyJars') { 
        ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
        delete ext.collection
        copy { from configurations.compile into genLibDir }
        copy { from fixedLibDir into genLibDir }
    }

    task('setupAll', dependsOn: ['copyJars','eclipse']) {
        description = 'Update jars from remote repositories and then fix eclipse classpath for master project'

    }

    hello << {println "- I depend on stserver"}

    build << { println "subproject:source sets=$sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs" }
}

task release << { println "putting together release" }

//TODO: have a release task AND if version is null when running the release task
//throw an exception telling the user to pass in a version with "./build -Dversion=xxxx"
//The automated build will call the release task with a version number like that
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(release) && version == 'Developer-Build') {
        throw new StopExecutionException("You must specify -Dversion=<some version> to run the release task")
    } else {
        version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

FULL child webserver build.gradle file

```
sourceSets.main{
  java.srcDirs = ['app']
}

build << { println "source sets=$sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs" }

hello << {println "- Do something specific xxxx"}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'play-1.2.4/framework', include: '*.jar')
    }

    eclipse {
    }
```

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you have some other code which resolves (i.e. asks for its files) the `compile` configuration at configuration time. Something like `configurations.compile.each { ... }`, *outside* a task action. After a configuration has been resolved, you can't add further dependencies to it. Usually it's undesirable (and unnecessary) to resolve a configuration at configuration time. Among other things, it will slow down your build.

See the [Gradle user guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for more information on the distinct phases of a Gradle build (initialization/configuration/execution).

Comment: I added the full files as I just don't see/get it.  All I do is move that code from master build.gradle to child build.gradle and it no longer works.  I don't have very fancy build scripts since I am just getting started with gradle.